# Windows 10 XAML Grouped GridView Scrolling

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, windows-10, uwp

Is it possible to have a grouped GridView with vertical scrolling of groups, but horizontal scrolling of items?

Meaning that every group is only one row, and you can scroll horizontally to view all items in that group.

Comment: Would my answer to this post help? stackoverflow.com/questions/27611135/setting-the-groupstyle-panel-of-a-listview-on-windows-phone

Comment: Very interesting, will try it out - but it seems promising :-)